# Node js JQuery Ajax json_encode equivalent

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

So, I have a JQuery Ajax client side. But now I want to handle the ajax post Node.js side.

I have my route and body parser.

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res){
    var firstname           = req.body.firstname;
    var lastname            = req.body.lastname;
    var email               = req.body.email;
    var password            = req.body.password;
    var confirm_password    = req.body.confirm_password;

    // Save into my database

         ...

    // Ajax callback return ???
});
```

In PHP I used `json_encode($array)` to get an ajax callback success. But how can I do that in node.js ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(array)`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with that I don't have any return. I set console.log('AJAX OK') inside my route and it works but the JSON.stringify returns me nothing

Comment: `JSON.stringify` returns json, just like `json_encode` does in PHP. It doesn't output anything. Are you asking how to send the json response? It looks like you're using express, so take a look at the [docs for the Response](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res). You could use: `res.json( array );`.

Comment: Oh yeah. res.json works perfectly. thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I made my comment into an answer since it seems to be the answer to your question anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you're using express and want to send a JSON response. You can use [res.json](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) for that.